# Remove text after multiple specific characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to combine two text columns, and then remove all text after a /, or (, or the word "with"

Example:
The combine of the two columns looks like this:

```
Select ,COALESCE(DT.Column1, '') + ' ' + COALESCE(M.Column2, '') AS Result1
from Table1 dt
join Table2 M on dt.M_Id =M.id
```

Result set looks like this currently:

```
SomeResults/Here
SomeMoreResults(here)
AndMoreResultsWITHthis
```

I need them to look like this:

```
SomeResults
SomeMoreResults
AndMoreResults
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) function:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Col LIKE '%/%' THEN SUBSTRING(Col, 1, CHARINDEX('/', Col)-1)
         WHEN Col LIKE '%(%' THEN SUBSTRING(Col, 1, CHARINDEX('(', Col)-1)
         WHEN Col LIKE '%WITH%' THEN SUBSTRING(Col, 1, CHARINDEX('WITH', Col)-1)
      END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left()`:

```
select (case when col like '%/%' and col  not like '%WITH%/%'
             then left(col, charindex('%/%', col)) - 1
             when col like '%WITH%'
             then left(col, charindex('%WITH%', col)) - 1
             else col
        end) as newcol
```

Note:  If caps are important for `'WITH'`, you might need to fiddle with collations as well.

Comment: Caps are not important, I used them only to reinforce my example. I am plugging this into my code now and testing it